# Summary or trimmed body field formatter does not display anything when the trim length is anything below 888

Tags: 7, views

I am creating a view for blog items to be displayed on the home page.

Obviously I would not want the whole blog to show on the home page and I want a summary of this to be displayed.

Whenever I set the summary to anything less than 888 it seems to delete the markup completely from the page.

Does anyone perhaps have a solution for me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I still don't know exactly what the solution to the issue with Drupal's own summary or trim option. I did however get the trim right using the Smart Trim Module. Thank you to the developers of the Smart Trim module.